# As3 - full screen interactive after NetConnection.call

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've this as3 code that from the Wowza server activates a function and returns a string. But once I get it, I can't go in Full Screen Interactive mode.

```
this.NetConnectionData.call("isUserPaid",new Responder(function(data:Object):void {
    var val:String=data.isUserPaid+"";
    if(val == "true") {
           this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
    } else {
            Alert.show("Error!");
    }

}),nomeUser);
```

And btw, in Html part I've already set "params.allowfullscreeninteractive = true;"

It's a bug or have I done something wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe docs [state](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS58a13becbbb904c7-28cf6d32136e60de784-8000.html) that FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE mode can only be set in response to mouse or keyboard click, so you can't set it from your call responder callback.